# how do I iterate over the tags present in a div tag

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeautifulSoup. 
Here's the html segment I'm interested in:

```
<div class="jpag" id="srchpagination"><a rel='prev' class="dis"><span>&lsaquo;&lsaquo;</span> Prev</a><span class="act">1</span><a 
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-2' >2</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-3' >3</a><a 
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-4' >4</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-5' >5</a><a 
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-6' >6</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-7' >7</a><a 
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-8' >8</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-9' >9</a><a 
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-10' >10</a><a rel='next' href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-2'>Next 
<span>&rsaquo;&rsaquo;</span></a></div>
```

I want to check if the value of last page number within the 'a' tag is 10.
I was able to get the  tag using this command:

```
atags1=bSoup.find('div' ,attrs={'class' : 'jpag'})
```

Now I want to iterate over the 'a' tags which has no attributes like rel="prev" or rel="next" so that I will be iterate through 'a' tags with just the page number. Please help me with that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do it, a simple way is to select the anchors in the  div and filter any that have a `rel` atttribute:

```
html = """<div class="jpag" id="srchpagination"><a rel='prev' class="dis"><span>&lsaquo;&lsaquo;</span> Prev</a><span class="act">1</span><a
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-2' >2</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-3' >3</a><a
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-4' >4</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-5' >5</a><a
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-6' >6</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-7' >7</a><a
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-8' >8</a><a href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-9' >9</a><a
href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-10' >10</a><a rel='next' href='http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-2'>Next
<span>&rsaquo;&rsaquo;</span></a></div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.select("#srchpagination a[href]"):
    if not a.get("rel"):
        print(a)
```

Which would give you:

```
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-2">2</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-3">3</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-4">4</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-5">5</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-6">6</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-7">7</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-8">8</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-9">9</a>
<a href="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Carpenters/ct-310711/page-10">10</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. If i want to iterate through the values present in those hrefs, like 1,2 ...10, how do i go about that?

Comment: No worries, `a.text` will give you each number, `a["href"]` will get you the link